# Count elements after the document gets transformed using XSLT with streaming

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0, accumulator

To complete the task from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62850634/a-better-way-to-use-streaming-in-xslt-3-0/62851525) I also need to count certain elements of the document I am getting after the transformation has been done.
Typically, when dealing with small documents, one could just put the initial output to a variable and then apply templates to it, something like

```
<xsl:template match=/*>
    <xsl:variable name="phase1">
        <Transformed>
            ...
        </Transformed>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates mode="step2" select="$phase1/*"/>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="step2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="step2"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Transformed/DocumentTotal/text()" mode="step2">
   <xsl:value-of select="count(/Transformed//*[some predicate here]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But I have to be able to process large documents, so I am neither want to copy result to a variable, nor to process it in non-streamable mode. I took a look at `<xsl:accumulator` and already wrote one allows me to count certain elements in **source** document, but now I got stuck having no idea how to perform such a count of the elements in the **result** document, could someone help me, please?

Comment: I don't think there is way doing that in one transformation, you would need to chain two transformations and use the accumulator in the second transformation. Chaining transformations should be doable from the API with http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Xslt30Transformer.html#asDocumentDestination-net.sf.saxon.s9api.Destination-.

Answer (score 1):

There's a range of techniques for this, none of them especially satisfactory. They include:

(a) run another pass over the output document:
(a1) within the same XSLT stylesheet, using a variable
(a2) in a second XSLT stylesheet
(a3) using some technology other than XSLT, e.g. a post-processing SAX filter

(b) run some computation on the input document that works out how many items will be present in the result, independently of actually producing those results. The viability of these of course varies greatly depending on the actual conditions.

(c) use some processor extension that allows you to increment a counter as a side-effect of generating an output item (for example saxon:assign - this is the principal use case for retaining that instruction).